# Lambda in VPC timeouts when calling public apigateway url

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, vpc-endpoint

We have lambda connected to Kinesis that sends data to a Websocket connection via Apigateway.  Lambda sits in the VPC and there is also VPC Endpoint to service: `com.amazon.us-east-1.execute-api.`

The problem is that call (from lambda) times out when performing REST operation on

`https://{apigatewayid}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/{stage}/@connections/{connection id}.   Host {apigatewayid}.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` gets resolved to private ip address like 10.0.11.22

Is there a way to make it work with VPC Endpoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

AWS Lambda functions in a VPC will never have a public IP address. This means they either need a route to a NAT Gateway to access things outside the VPC, or a route to a VPC endpoint for the specific non-VPC AWS services they need to access. In your case an [API Gateway Private Endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/) would be appropriate.

Comment: Hey @mark-b  - thanks vm for this link, however it requires a private ApiGateway though.  Would you know what should be a VPC structure if ApiGateway is public?  Thanks!

Comment: Does your Lambda really need to be in the VPC? If so, I think you may have to configure it to be in private subnets with routes to a NAT Gateway.